# How to paste the copied text from LibreOffice to the text editor

Tags: libreoffice, text-editor, copy-and-paste

The text editor in Ubuntu 18.04 is not showing the paste option. I am trying to copy some text from LibreOffice Writer and paste it in the Text editor, but it is not working.

[image: Text Editor not showing paste option]

First I couldn't see any paste option in the text editor. I also tried Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V, but they didn't work.

Comment: Can you detail more? Are you talking about LibreOffice Writer? Did you create the file?
I opened my Open Office Writer, type random letters, select, right clic and the copy option was there. I'm guessing you opened a only read file, or even a picture.

Comment: Sorry I provided less detail. I copied some text from LibreOffice Calc to Libre Office Writer and then copied from Libre Office Writer to Text Editor. It did not work. It is a graphic text. But when I copied directly from Libre Office Calc to Text Editor, it worked. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you doble clic in the cell to select the text you want to copy in Calc? In that way, you will copy the text itself and not the cell. Maybe some screenshoots can help a little

Comment: Please [edit] your question with further details - which version of LO and which text editor. The default TE in Ubuntu does indeed have a paste option accessed by the right mouse button. Please also be aware that v18.04 is shortly to become EOL See https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-18-04-eol-for-devices

Comment: Hi, I have added the imgae to show that text editor doesn't have paste option. I did the paste directly from Libre Office Calc to text Editor. Zulfi,

Comment: Hi @Henry Corredor, Text Editor doesn't show paste option while copying from LibreOffice Writer to TextEditor.

Comment: How is your LibreOffice installed ?
Classic installation from official repository in APT/.deb packaging format ?
Or something else like, for example, snap ?

Comment: @Coeur Noir Hi, It was already installed by Vendor, Linux Certified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy some text in LibreOffice Writer and open the text editor.
2. Click in the text document where you want the text to be pasted.
3. Click once with the middle button of the mouse to paste the text or right-click anywhere in the text editor to show a context menu and select *Paste* from the context menu.